# Markov chain stats period

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

[image: Markov chain stats period]

Suppose we have the following Markov chain with some transition probabilities. Clearly the period of stat 1 is 1. But what is the period of stat 2? I suspect it is 1 as well. But is it so and can you please explain it with respect to the definition, $d(i)=gcd\{n|P_{ii}(n)>0\}$?

Comment: An element in State 2 has to go somewhere . . . where does it go? Your drawing does not indicate this

Comment: Is it part of Markov Chain definition that the process must make a transaction to some stat (possibly to itself) at each step?

Comment: What is your probability transition matrix?

Comment: O.k., now I see it. The row has to sum to 1, thus this type of graph is not possible. Thanks.